# Netplan bridge for VMS kills internet

Tags: networking, server, wireless, ethernet, netplan

Here is my netplan yaml file:

```
network:
version: 2
renderer: NetworkManager
ethernets:
    eth0:
        dhcp4: true
        optional: true
wifis:
    wlan0:
        optional: true
        access-points:
             "redacted":
                 password: "redacted"
        dhcp4: true
bonds:
    bond0:
        dhcp4: true
        interfaces: [ eth0, wlan0 ]
        nameservers:
            addresses: [ 192.168.1.5, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4 ]
        parameters:
            mode: active-backup
            primary: wlan0
bridges:
    br0:
        addresses: [ 10.0.1.1/24 ]
        interfaces: [ bond0 ]
        dhcp4: false
        nameservers:
            search: [ local ]
            addresses: [ 192.168.1.5, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4 ]
```

I'm trying to use bond0 as a "backup". If the wifi fails to connect then it tries to use ethernet.
I want to use bond0 as the interface for my bridge so that it can switch between the two.
No matter what I do, bridging kills the wifi. I'm not sure if it kills the ethernet or not.
Also, netplan didn't use my DNS configuration correctly unless I set the renderer to NetworkManager.
There was the same issue with brctl. Bridging ethernet and wifi was unsupported and hacks needed to be used.
Is there something I can do to use br0 with bond0? I don't mind if it's pretty technical(or hacky).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it work by wrapping the bond in a vlan:

```
bonds:
    bond0:
        dhcp4: true
        interfaces: [ eth0, wlan0 ]
        nameservers:
            addresses: [ 192.168.1.5, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4 ]
        parameters:
            mode: active-backup
            primary: wlan0
vlans:
    vlan0:
        id: 0
        link: bond0
bridges:
    br0:
        addresses: [ 10.0.1.1/24 ]
        interfaces: [ vlan0 ]
```

I love how StackExchange punishes you for posting easy questions but never answers the hard ones! It's definitely not what it used to be.